# ASUS ROG GX700VO RAM a mistake?

Tags: laptop, gaming

The [ASUS ROG GX700VO](https://www.asus.com/sg/ROG-Republic-Of-Gamers/ROG-GX700VO/specifications/) has the following specs

- [Intel i7 6820HK Processor](https://ark.intel.com/products/88969/Intel-Core-i7-6820HK-Processor-8M-Cache-up-to-3_60-GHz)
- RAM up to DDR4 2800MHz

The "Memory Types" of [Intel i7 6820HK](https://ark.intel.com/products/88969/Intel-Core-i7-6820HK-Processor-8M-Cache-up-to-3_60-GHz) are stated as "DDR4-2133, LPDDR3-1866, DDR3L-1600", meaning to say the CPU can only support up to RAM speed of 2133. Isnt it a bit overkill to have a DDR4 up to 2800MHz?

Comment: No, I'm going to post about this soon, but it has to do with XMP.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

## TL;DR: Maybe sort of, but not for the reason you're thinking.

#### Memory overclocking and XMP

Intel specifies that their CPUs (here, the [6820HK](https://ark.intel.com/products/88969/Intel-Core-i7-6820HK-Processor-8M-Cache-up-to-3_60-GHz)) are guaranteed to work with DDR4-2133, LPDDR3-1866, and DDR3L-1600. Anything beyond that isn't officially part of their specifications, or guaranteed to work. However, in practice, it will.

What's going on here is overclocking–basically, pushing stuff beyond it's manufacturer rated speeds. This practice isn't unsafe, and, in the case of memory, is basically supported by the manufacturer. Here, the RAM manufacturer certifies that the RAM will work at 2800 MHz, and the motherboard manufacturer certifies that the motherboard can support overclocking memory to those speeds. Similarly, Intel allows their CPUs to work with overclocked RAM (and effectively guarantees it will work.)

Because memory overclocking takes work, Intel created something called XMP, or Extreme Memory Profile. Basically, this is a list of settings stored on the memory modules that tell the motherboard what speeds it says it can overclock to and timings are required, then loads (usually automatically) those settings. Though this isn't really as important for your system (since it's a prebuilt), the technology is the same as any desktop, and is still applicable if you decide to upgrade your memory down the line. The end result is the same though: the memory runs at its "overclocked" speed.

#### RAM speed as an asset

Though I won't dive into it too much, how much–if at all–RAM speed matters depends on your workload. [This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D_Yt4vSZKVk) does a much better job examining it then I could ever do, but the basic conclusion is that it matters a little in some games (more on Ryzen then other platforms) and varies widely for other workloads. If you're building for gaming, don't sweat it too much; if you're building for some other task, Google around and see what other people have experienced.